# Can not get cypress to work in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, cypress

I want to run cypress in docker container and for this purpose i created.
For this i followed some guides and tutorials

1. e2e directory that has `Dockerfile`

```
FROM cypress/base:14
WORKDIR /app

# dependencies will be installed only if the package files change
COPY package.json .
COPY cypress.json .

RUN npm install
RUN npx cypress open
RUN npx cypress verify
```

```
cypress.json
```

```
  {
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
    "reporter": "junit",
    "reporterOptions": {
      "mochaFile": "cypress/results/output.xml"
    }
  }
```

```
package.json
```

```
{
    "name": "e2e",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Cypress tests",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
      "cypress": "9.5.0"
    }
}
```

and `.npmrc`

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
save-exact=true
progress=false
package-lock=true
```

2. modified `docker-compose.yml` at the root to be

   ````
   version: '3.8'
   services:
   nextjsApp: 
       // rest    
   cypress:
       image: "cypress/included:3.2.0"
       depends_on:
         - nextjs
       environment:
         - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://nextjs:3000
       working_dir: /e2e
       command: npx cypress run
       volumes:
         - ./:/e2e
   networks:
     backend:
       external: true```
   ````

Running docker-compose build does not cause or show any errors
But when i run `docker-compose up` i get

```
cypress_1  | Could not find any tests to run.
cypress_1  | 
cypress_1  | We looked but did not find a cypress.json file in this folder: /e2e
```

How can this be solved ?